# How can I convert a list of dict keyx:valuex to a list dict key:keyx, value:valuex?

Tags: python

So I have a list like this:

```
  [ 
    { '1234' : 'Sun'}
    { '353453' : 'Earth'}
    ...
  ]
```

I want to convert this to

```
  [ 
    { 'temp': '1234', 'planet' : 'Sun'}
    { 'temp': '353453', 'planet': 'Earth'}
    ...
  ]
```

What's the Pythonic way to have this list of dict converted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list/dictionary comprehension:

```
lst =   [ 
    { '1234' : 'Sun'},
    { '353453' : 'Earth'}
  ]

out = [ { 'temp': k, 'planet': v } for l in lst for k, v in l.items() ]

# [{'temp': '1234', 'planet': 'Sun'}, {'temp': '353453', 'planet': 'Earth'}]
```

Comment: Or `[dict(zip(('temp', 'planet'), *d.items())) for d in lst]` if you prefer non-nested list-comp.

Comment: @timgeb nice! it took me a good look to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t try to do it in a one liner, it wouldn't be readable. You should construct the output list for each element one by one.

The fellow that will read your code later (and this might be yourself in a couple of month) will thank you.

You can do something like

```
a = [{'1234': 'Sun', "12": "mars"}]

output = []
for measurement in a:
    output_list_of_dict = [{"temp": temp, "planet": planet} for temp, planet in measurement.items()]
    output.extend(output_list_of_dict)
```

Note that in each loop turn, the result is a list itself : one dictionary may contain several temperatures. Therefore I used «extend» method, which merges the lists, and not append.

Doing it in an explicit and readable way conforms to the python philosophy.

It is the most pythonic in this sense.

Comment: That's nice, but you definitely changed the question in your answer. The original poster never stated that one dictionnary could contain several couples of planet/temperature. And why use several dictionnaries if it is allowed ? Also why not several measures for the same planet if you go that way. I upvoted anyway as I agree with the use of oneliner (avoid it for readability). But you are not really answering the question.

Comment: it's true he never said that, it just seemed likely given the dict that he posted.

 But it still works even you have just one key-value in each dict.

also, he didn't say it could contain several temperatures measurements, but didn't say it would contain just one either

Comment: Just Occam's razor

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean I changed the question. the solution still answers his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head I would write something like below:

```
>>> l = [{ '1234' : 'Sun'}, { '353453' : 'Earth'}]
>>> r = [{'temp':list(x.keys())[0], 'planet': x[list(x.keys())[0]]}  for x in l if len(x) == 1]
```

The core issue is that this will only work with a correctly formed input data structure, and this is not guaranteed in any way by the input format. Hencefore a prior validation of input data may be useful.

But if I had to put that kind of thing in production code, I would certainly avoid oneliner as suggested by @François-Dailloux and write instead the stupid and simple code below, which is also very readable and also likely faster:

```
l = [{ '1234' : 'Sun'}, { '353453' : 'Earth'}]
res = []
for d in l:
    if len(d) == 1:
        for k, v in d.items():
            res.append('temp': k, 'planet': v)
```

If the len is not as expected I would also of course raise some exception to avoid propagation of broken input data.

Comment: that will not work on python 3 you need to add `list` on `x.keys()` like this : `list(x.keys())` otherwise you will got error `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Right; I will fix that